# What is dnndev.me? (React Native Share link on Facebook shows as dnndev.me)

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

I'm currently working on a simple share function where I can share a news article via the URL (I.E. https://www.nrps.nl/Nieuws/Nieuwsitem.aspx?ID=812). I'm using React Native Share for this (code below). When sharing on Facebook it shows up as dnndev.me instead of nrps.nl, what I expected it to be. Clicking the dnndev.me link redirects to `https://www.nrps.nl/Nieuws/Nieuwsitem.aspx?ID=812&fbclid=IwAR3Eq-j1wX8GUVvSEvhFNu85k8U_vjmV0l4_ycF-AUhoV61YBIieRGJgQg4` instead of `https://www.nrps.nl/Nieuws/Nieuwsitem.aspx?ID=812`, but the content is the same. (if I shouldn't show any of this, please edit it out. I don't know what the extra string means)

From what I can tell, dnndev.me seems to be a development environment. 
The questions:

1. What is dnndev.me, besides some sort of host?
2. Can I do anything to work around it showing up as dnndev.me or can I only inform NRPS that they haven't done so already?

RN code:

```
let message = `${news.Title}\n${news.Image}\n${news.MessageUrl}`
```

news.title is a simple string. news.image is a URL to an image, news.MessageUrl is the URL of the news article itself. I've tested it with only the MessageUrl and it has the same result.

```
 try {
  const result = await Share.share({
    message: `${message}`,
  });
  if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
    if (result.activityType) {
      // shared with activity type of result.activityType
    } else {
      // shared
    }
  } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
    // dismissed
    console.log("Sharing dismissed")
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

**EDIT**:

What I want to happen is to have the auto generated square / content field (or however it's called) like follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPvYH.jpg

Comment: I'm guessing it's for analytics purposes. The `fbclid=....` param is definitely for reporting a click event to Facebook analytics API

Comment: This seems to be the case indeed. Do you know if there's a way to remove this parameter all together (not just Google Analytics)? It's just clutter. The app is meant as full release and users might not be comfortable with such a URL / tracker (if they know what it is).

Comment: Though knowing Facebook you can't..

Comment: _“When sharing on Facebook it shows up as dnndev.me instead of nrps.nl”_ - that’s because the canonical URL is set to one below the dnndev.me domain, as simply debugging the URL easily shows: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nrps.nl%2FNieuws%2FNieuwsitem.aspx%3FID%3D812

Comment: No, you can not fix this yourself - the nrps.nl people will have to fix this on their end, so that their system gives out the correct canonical URL for this piece of content in the first place. With how it is currently specified, the `dnndev.me` URL _is_ to be considered the “real” URL of this piece of content - specifying that is what canonical _is for_, after all.

Comment: Ah, thank you all for the info. I'll pass it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dnndev.me` is a web server. As a web server, it notifies facebook of any problems in managing and operating facebook data and also solves any problems.

[webSite of dnndev.me](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/)
And the `fbclid` behind the existing parameters is the visitor tracking system ID.

> The acronym for fbclid is: "Facebook Click Identifier". It means a
>   Facebook click identifier.

It's about `Facebook` clicks.
These are parameters introduced for accurate statistics from this data.
We're also going to exchange data with `Google Annalysis` and `AdSense`.
Make more accurate estimates of visitors.

To share Facebook, you can use the following modules to work around it: This solution is contained in the Facebook developer's official document.

1. `$yarn add react-native-fbsdk or npm install --save react-native-fbsdk`
2. `$ react-native link react-native-fbsdk`

Note For iOS using cocoapods, run:

3. `$ cd ios/ && pod install`

### Usage

```js
import { ShareDialog } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
let message = `${news.Title}\n${news.Image}\n${news.MessageUrl}`
const shareLinkContent = {
         contentType: 'link',
          contentUrl: "https://www.nrps.nl/Nieuws/Nieuwsitem.aspx?ID=812",
  contentDescription: message,
};
...
this.state = {shareLinkContent: shareLinkContent,};
...
shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
  var tmp = this;
  ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
    function(canShow) {
      if (canShow) {
        return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
      }
    }
  ).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('Share operation was cancelled');
      } else {
        alert('Share was successful with postId: '
          + result.postId);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert('Share failed with error: ' + error.message);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. Thank you. Do you know if NRPS would be able to change the banner that pops up to something that makes more sense (I.E. the example I gave in the edit on OP)?

Comment: @04FS Look at the title of the question. I'm asking what this is. So I just wrote down a description and a link to it.

Comment: I might not have been entirely clear. This answer did help since I partly asked what dnndev.me was in the first place. Now I just need to find out what I can do against the links showing up as such, as I'm not the developer of their website. Updated the post for more clarity.

Comment: You can look at the question title all day long, that doesn’t change the fact that “As a web server, it notifies facebook of any problems in managing and operating facebook data and also solves any problems” make zero sense here. `dnndev.me` is just the development domain `nrps.nl` are using here - it has absolutely nothing to do with “notifying facebook” of _anything_ here.

Comment: The notifying facebook thing was on me. I got confused to what the extra token was when posting it to facebook. This answer helped explaining that.

Comment: @SanderKoldenhof I edited the answer to Facebook URL sharing.